# Retrieve current value of ARITHABORT

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm debugging a strange behavior which seems to be related to ARITHABORT. How can I retrieve the current value of ARITHABORT for the active connection?

cheers,
Achim

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
select SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT')
```

[returns 1 or 0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175001.aspx), depending on whether it's on or off

Answer (score 5):

`@@OPTIONS` allows you to get the a bitfield of current values that are set for the current session.
The bitfield can be interpreted with following script.

```
DECLARE @options INT 
SELECT @options = @@OPTIONS 

PRINT @options
IF ( (1 & @options) = 1 ) PRINT 'DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK' 
IF ( (2 & @options) = 2 ) PRINT 'IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS' 
IF ( (4 & @options) = 4 ) PRINT 'CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT' 
IF ( (8 & @options) = 8 ) PRINT 'ANSI_WARNINGS' 
IF ( (16 & @options) = 16 ) PRINT 'ANSI_PADDING' 
IF ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS' 
IF ( (64 & @options) = 64 ) PRINT 'ARITHABORT' 
IF ( (128 & @options) = 128 ) PRINT 'ARITHIGNORE'
IF ( (256 & @options) = 256 ) PRINT 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' 
IF ( (512 & @options) = 512 ) PRINT 'NOCOUNT' 
IF ( (1024 & @options) = 1024 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON' 
IF ( (2048 & @options) = 2048 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF' 
IF ( (4096 & @options) = 4096 ) PRINT 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL' 
IF ( (8192 & @options) = 8192 ) PRINT 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT' 
IF ( (16384 & @options) = 16384 ) PRINT 'XACT_ABORT'
```